# Honda Civic DX dash temperature gauge malfunctioning?

Tags: honda, electrical, civic, troubleshooting, gauges

My 2001 Civic DX has a issue with the temp gauge in the dash. The needle has traveled to the opposite side than it normally registers on. Meaning it is pointing to the left away from the temp increments on the right side where it normally registers.It registers the same with the sending unit connected or disconnected so it is kind of hard to tell what my motor temp is? What could cause this and how can I repair it?

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect the sender unit and check the continuity with an ohm meter. If if measures open circuit the sender is faulty and should be replaced.

Comment: It can be not open circuit and still be faulty, a rough temperature-resistance table is needed to figure out if it's any good.